# Android Dialogs stored and accessed via separate class

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm having a stack overflow error relating to android dialogs. I have around 21 dialogs contained within a which statement using showDialog(DIALOG1); to display the dialogs which works great when both the dialogs and the main activity are contained within the same class file but once I move the dialogs into another class file and try to access them from the main activity it causes a stack overflow error. I've tried extending the Dialog class in the dialog class as well as extending the class that contains the dialogs(main activity extends classOfDialogs). I can not seem to get the dialogs to work being accessed from another file. Any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Stack Trace (or what I could gather

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception StackOverflowError))    
Looper.myLooper() line: 137 
Handler.<init>() line: 119  
AlphaAthensActivity(Activity).<init>() line: 679    
AlphaAthensActivity(Dialogs).<init>() line: 13  
AlphaAthensActivity.<init>() line: 55   
AlphaAthensActivity(Dialogs).<init>() line: 36  
AlphaAthensActivity.<init>() line: 55   
AlphaAthensActivity(Dialogs).<init>() line: 36  
AlphaAthensActivity.<init>() line: 55   
Class.newInstanceImpl() line: not available [native method] 
Class.newInstance() line: 1429  
Instrumentation.newActivity(ClassLoader, String, Intent) line: 1021 
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2577  
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679   
ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: my apology I'm new to stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling this Activity's Dialog recursively.

```
AlphaAthensActivity(Activity).<init>() line: 679    
AlphaAthensActivity(Dialogs).<init>() line: 13  
AlphaAthensActivity.<init>() line: 55   
AlphaAthensActivity(Dialogs).<init>() line: 36  
AlphaAthensActivity.<init>() line: 55   
AlphaAthensActivity(Dialogs).<init>() line: 36  
AlphaAthensActivity.<init>() line: 55
```

To avoid the application running out of memory, this exception is thrown. I think you need to redesign your code. A better idea will be to have the Dialogs in a common base class and extend it.

Comment: an see thats what I have now, if I include the dialogs into the main activity class everything works fine but the seconds I move them to a common base class and extend it I get this stack overflow